# Border BorderBrush Color in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: wpf, xaml

i have a code in xaml something like this.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="BorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5" />
                ...
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>

<Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
...

<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" ...
```

The thing is, if i use this control in windows 7 64 bit there is no border color! I already tried a few combinations  with Style in Control.Resource and without Style at all, but result is always the same.
If not using DataTemplate everything is fine, so seems like i should do something with DataTemplate. 
Can anyone help me to solve this damn problem. :)

Comment: Why do you mention the OS, does it work on others?

Comment: Yep. in win 7 32 bit. no problem.

Comment: well i just found an answer. 

I just check BorderThickness under Windows 7 64 bit for two values 0.7 and 1 and everything is fine :) but if i use value 0.5 i have the same problem!

Comment: 64bit probably handles the rounding differently, why don't you use integer values? Floating point values usually aren't being displayed nicely anyway.

Comment: well seems like it's a good point to start using integer values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check BorderThickness under Windows 7 64 bit for two values 0.7 and 1 and everything is fine :) but if i use value 0.5 i have the same problem! 
Use integer values.